# How can I do myprog.exe -param1 -param2 -param3CRLF -param4 under Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I do:

```
myprog.exe -param1 -param2 -param3CRLF -param4
```

under Windows?
I mean- I want myprog.exe to understand that param3 comes with a newline on the end.

I cannot change myprog.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD is not very flexible regarding data that it can operate on. Newlines fall under the category of special characters that are difficult to work with.

This could be accomplished with PowerShell, which should be available on any recent version of Windows. There *is* an escape character in PoSH that could be used for this purpose (`n is a newline).

```
C:\> PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "perl sub.pl -param1 -param2 """-param3`n^""" -param4" 
'-param1'
'-param2'
'-param3
'
'-param4'
```

I don't have myprog.exe, so I used `sub.pl`:

```
print("'".join("'\n'",@ARGV)."'");
```